# Close popover when clicked outside (body)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have popovers like this:

```
<div class="slbb-popover popover top" role="tooltip">
   <div class="arrow"></div>
   <h2 class="popover-title">Speelland</h2>
   <div class="popover-content">And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? </div>
   <div class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-primary'>Meer informatie</a></div>
</div>
```

I trigger them in JavaScript and give them display block. Now I want to close them when I click outside (body) but this code will only do it once:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
  if(e.target.className == "btn-pointer")
      return;

  //For descendants of menu_content being clicked, remove this check if you do not want to put constraint on descendants.
  if($(e.target).closest('.btn-pointer').length)
      return;

  console.log('check1');

  //Do processing of click event here for every element except with id menu_content
  if($('.popover').css('display') == 'block') {
       $('.popover').css('display', 'none');
       console.log('check2');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample:

```
$(function() {

  var 
    status = false;

  $('body').click(function() {

    if (!status) {

      // VIEW POPUP WINDOW
      status = true;
    }
    else {

      // CLOSE POPUP WINDOW
      status = false;
    }

  });
});
```

[Demo (`with window.open()`)](https://jsfiddle.net/761qg9g5/)